# Printing net-snmp getbulk results with newlines at each index

Tags: python, networking, tuples, net-snmp

I have the following Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import netsnmp

session = netsnmp.Session(DestHost='_destination address_', Version=2, Community='_string_')

vars = netsnmp.VarList(netsnmp.Varbind('ifIndex',), netsnmp.Varbind('ifDescr',), netsnmp.Varbind('ifOperStatus',))

print(session.getbulk(0, 48, vars))
```

The results of `session.getbulk` are as follows:

```
('1', 'Vlan1', '1', '2', 'Vlan2', '2', '10101', 'GigabitEthernet0/1', '2', '10102',
'GigabitEthernet0/2', '2', '10103', 'GigabitEthernet0/3', '2', '10104', 
'GigabitEthernet0/4', '2', '10105', 'GigabitEthernet0/5', '2', '10106', 
'GigabitEthernet0/6', '2', '10107', 'GigabitEthernet0/7', '2', '10108', 
'GigabitEthernet0/8', '2', '10109', 'GigabitEthernet0/9', '2', '10110', 
'GigabitEthernet0/10', '2', '10111', 'GigabitEthernet0/11', '2', '10112',  
'GigabitEthernet0/12', '2', '10113', 'GigabitEthernet0/13', '1', '10114', 
'GigabitEthernet0/14', '1', '10115', 'GigabitEthernet0/15', '2', '10116', 
'GigabitEthernet0/16', '1', '10117', 'GigabitEthernet0/17', '2')
```

I would like to print the information returned by `session.getbulk` on a newline per each interface. If my understanding of my program is correct, I should get three values for each interface, (`ifIndex`, `ifDescr`, and `ifOperStatus`.)

As it stands, the results are presented in a single block of information, and it may be hard for my audience to differentiate between.

However, being totally new to programming I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this. If anybody is willing to point me toward an appropriate tutorial or documentation for this, I'd much appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, I think this is what you want?:

```
result = session.getbulk(0, 48, vars)
for i in range(0, len(result), 3):
    print "ifind: "+result[i]+" ifdesc: "+result[i+1]+" status: "+result[i+2]
```

Comment: Yes, this was precisely what I was too dense to figure out!

Thank you for your reply, I understand now that I see it done how simple it was.